# How to get a random filename from a directory and using it within a command?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sox, random

`play ~/Music/audio0.flac repeat -`

A command for playing a single specific audio file on repeat.

`play ~/Music/${random_audio_file} repeat -`

A pseudo command for playing a single **random audio file from the given directory (`~/Music/`)**, also on repeat.

---

How to do the latter as a real working command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the `shuf` command for that.
Try:

```
play "$(find ~/Music -name '*.flac' | shuf -n 1)" repeat -
```

The double quotes are necessary in case your filenames may contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This command will get a random `.flac` file and play it using `omxplayer`.
Modify the command to suite your player.

```
find . -type f -name '*.flac' | shuf -n 1 | xargs -d "\n" omxplayer
```